# Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 Error message in Wordpress using WooCommerce

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I realize there's quite a few of these questions answered and all are unique in their own way. Above is the error message that appeared over this weekend and I can't find a solution for the life of me. I mange to open up the file in Siteground's File Manager and here are the lines in question. What can I do to fix this error?

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/customer/www/myapx.shop/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php on line 1184

Codebase

```
            if ( 'repeater' === $control_obj->get_type() ) {
        foreach ( $settings[ $control_name ] as & $field ) {
            $field = $this->parse_dynamic_settings( $field, $control['fields'], $field );
        }

        continue;
    }

    $dynamic_settings = $control_obj->get_settings( 'dynamic' );

    if ( ! empty( $control['dynamic'] ) ) {
        $dynamic_settings = array_merge( $dynamic_settings, $control['dynamic'] );
    }

    if ( empty( $dynamic_settings ) || ! isset( $all_settings[ Manager::DYNAMIC_SETTING_KEY ][ $control_name ] ) ) {
        continue;
    }
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

P.S. Go easy on me not very technical.

Comment: The code is [here](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/master/includes/base/controls-stack.php) if anyone else wants to try and figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and it seems to be from the current update of the Elementor plugin. See this post:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-with-new-update-2-9-2/

In my case, there was a conflict with an Add on for elementor, I reverted to version 2.8.5 of the plugin and the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you so much Geoffrey. Im doing a back up now then rolling back Elementor. I read this article but wasn't sure i'd work. I'll keep you guys posted.